# Hibernate updates only selected columns instead of all modified fields

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb

I have an entity:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "my_dto" )
public class MyDto implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( generator = "uuid" )
    @GenericGenerator( name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid" )
    private String id;
    private String displayName;
    private String remark;
    @Column( name = "BACKGROUND" )
    private Integer backgroundColorInt;
    @Column( name = "FOREGROUND" )
    private Integer foregroundColorInt;

    private boolean isBold;
    private boolean isItalic;
    private boolean isUnderlined;
    @Column( name = "ISBLINKINGACTIVE" )
    private Boolean blinkingActive;
    @Column( name = "ISBLINKINGBOLD" )
    private Boolean blinkingBold;
    @Column( name = "ISBLINKINGITALIC" )
    private Boolean blinkingItalic;
    @Column( name = "ISBLINKINGUNDERLINED" )
    private Boolean blinkingUnderlined;
    @Column( name = "BLINKINGBACKGROUND" )
    private Integer blinkingBackColorInt;
    @Column( name = "BLINKINGFOREGROUND" )
    private Integer blinkingForeColorInt;

    @Column
    private String createdBy;
    @Column
    private Date createDat;
    @Column
    private String changedBy;
    @Column
    private Date changeDat;
    @Version
    private int version;

    @Transient
    private Map< String, Object > appearanceConfig = null;

    @PostLoad
    public void copyMyDto2AppearanceConfig()
    {
        if( appearanceConfig == null )
        {
            appearanceConfig = new HashMap< String, Object >();
        }
        appearanceConfig.put( BACKGROUND_COLOR, backgroundColorInt );
        appearanceConfig.put( FOREGROUND_COLOR, foregroundColorInt );
        appearanceConfig.put( FONT_STYLE, getFontStyle() );

        appearanceConfig.put( IS_BLINKING_ACTIVE, blinkingActive );
        HashMap< String, Object > blinkingConf = new HashMap< String, Object >();
        blinkingConf.put( FOREGROUND_COLOR, blinkingForeColorInt );
        blinkingConf.put( BACKGROUND_COLOR, blinkingBackColorInt );
        blinkingConf.put( FONT_STYLE, getBlinkingFontStyle() );
        appearanceConfig.put( BLINKING_CONFIGURATION, blinkingConf );
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void copyAppearanceConfig2MyDto()
    {
        setForegroundColor( (Integer)appearanceConfig.get( FOREGROUND_COLOR ) );
        setBackgroundColor( (Integer)appearanceConfig.get( BACKGROUND_COLOR ) );
        setFontStyle( (FontStyle[])appearanceConfig.get( FONT_STYLE ) );
        setBlinkingActive( Boolean.TRUE.equals( appearanceConfig.get( IS_BLINKING_ACTIVE ) ) );
        Map< String, Object > blinkingConf =
        (Map< String, Object >)appearanceConfig.get( BLINKING_CONFIGURATION );
        if( blinkingConf != null )
        {
            setBlinkingFontStyle( (FontStyle[])blinkingConf.get( FONT_STYLE ) );
            setBlinkingForegroundColor( (Integer)blinkingConf.get( FOREGROUND_COLOR ) );
            setBlinkingBackgroundColor( (Integer)blinkingConf.get( BACKGROUND_COLOR ) );
        }
        else
        {
            setBlinkingFontStyle( null );
            setBlinkingForegroundColor( (Integer)null );
            setBlinkingBackgroundColor( (Integer)null );
        }
    }

    // some standard getters and setters...
}
```

I have created a stateless EJB, packed it into the EAR package and deployed it to the JBoss server (Wildfly-10). I am now able to create / delete the `MyDto`'s from the database without any problems whatsoever. What concerns me is the update operation. The EJB's implementation of the update is as follows:

```
@Stateless
@Remote( MyDtoStorageServiceIf.class )
public class MyDtoStorageService implements MyDtoStorageServiceIf
{
    @PersistenceContext( unitName = "DS_MY_DTO", name = "DS_MY_DTO" )
    protected EntityManager entityManager;
    @Override
    public MyDto update( MyDto aMyDto )
    {
        MyDto myDto = entityManager.merge( aMyDto );
        entityManager.flush();
        return myDto;
    }
    // other EJB methods, e.g. persisting new MyDto object, deleting selected MyDto from database etc.
}
```

When I try to update the selected row it turns out only `displayName` and `remark` fields are updated in the database, even though some other fields of the `aMyDto` have also been modified. Is it possible that the reason lies in the @PreUpdate and @PostLoad methods in the `MyDto` class? As I am running short on ideas, I would like to ask you to point out the possible reasons for this weird behavior. What am I most likely missing? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Details are copied from your `appearanceConfig` hash map to the fields before Update happens.

If your `appearanceConfig` hash map is not having the latest changes, then the old values from that hash map will overwrite the changes.

On a related note, why not remove all the member fields and just write straight to the hash map? You could just have getters and setters, which directly set data to the hash map.